# How to read yaml file in Ada

Tags: yaml, ada

I'm trying to understand how to work with Ada and AdaYaml library (https://github.com/yaml/AdaYaml/). I have several yaml files and I need to transform them into Ada records for further processing.

After several hours of playing with library I have no clue how use Accessor to access yaml data.

My minimal somehow working code is

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line;

with Yaml.Source.File;
with Yaml.Source.Text_IO;
with Yaml.Dom.Loading;
with Yaml.Dom.Node;
with Yaml; use Yaml;
with Text; use Text;

procedure Load_Dom is
   Input : Source.Pointer;
begin
   
   if Ada.Command_Line.Argument_Count = 0 then
      Input := Yaml.Source.Text_IO.As_Source (Ada.Text_IO.Standard_Input);
   else
      Input := Yaml.Source.File.As_Source (Ada.Command_Line.Argument (1));
   end if;
   
   declare
      
      Document : Yaml.Dom.Document_Reference :=
        Yaml.Dom.Loading.From_Source (Input);
     
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Root node is a " & Yaml.Dom.Node.Instance'(Document.Root.Value).Kind'Img);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Root node is a " & Yaml.Dom.Node.Instance'(Document.Root.Value).Tag);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Root node is a " & Yaml.Dom.Node.Instance'(Document.Root.Value).Mapping_Style'Img);
   end;
end Load_Dom;
```

I think the explicit conversion `Yaml.Dom.Node.Instance'(Document.Root.Value)` is not right and I must be missing something.

Any idea or code example how to read yaml file in correct way?

Comment: `Yaml.Dom.Node.Instance'(Document.Root.Value)` is not a conversion. It's a *qualified expression*. It specifies that the expression within the parentheses is of the subtype given before the apostrophe. Qualified expressions are useful for disambiguating expressions that are otherwise ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the author of AdaYaml.

The `Accessor` which is returned by `Document.Root.Value` is defined as follows:

```vhdl
type Accessor (Data : not null access Node.Instance) is limited private
     with Implicit_Dereference => Data;
```

As any type with a discriminant, you can access the `Node.Instance` via its name, `Data`. So this explicit expression retrieves the root node's kind:

```vhdl
Document.Root.Value.Data.all.Kind
```

Now Ada allows us to make the pointer dereference implicit, dropping the `.all`:

```vhdl
Document.Root.Value.Data.Kind
```

And the `Implicit_Dereference` attribute of `Accessor` allows us to drop the `.Data`:

```vhdl
Document.Root.Value.Kind
```

So what you want to do is

```vhdl
declare
   Document : Yaml.Dom.Document_Reference :=
      Yaml.Dom.Loading.From_Source (Input);
   Root : Yaml.Dom.Accessor := Document.Root.Value; 
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Root node is a " & Root.Kind'Img);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Root node is a " & Root.Tag);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Root node is a " & Root.Mapping_Style'Img);
end;
```

This is shown briefly in [the documentation](https://ada.yaml.io/doc/Yaml.Dom/) but not explained. For further reading, [this gem](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-123-implicit-dereferencing-in-ada-2012) might be of interest.

Comment: This could just be me, but in GNAT CE 2020, and apart from `libadalang` having troubles parsing the source code (internal error), this only seems to compile with an explicit qualification `Yaml.Dom.Node.Instance'(Root)`. Without it, the compiler returns (e.g.) *undefined selector "Kind" for overloaded prefix*.

Comment: You can omit the qualification if you keep `Data`, so (e.g.) `Root.Data.Kind`. The aspect `Implicit_Dereference => Data` doesn't seem to work as expected (?).

Comment: I encountered exactly same problem. At the moment I'm not sure about version of GNAT. I will put it here later.

Comment: I admit that I did not test this for a long time, it did work back when I wrote the code. Creating a new `Node.Instance` will possibly copy an Indefinite_Vectors/Maps instance which is not ideal. I advice to go with `.Data`.

Comment: @DeeDee *undefined selector "Kind" for overloaded prefix* seems strange as the name `Root` should not be overloaded unless you do `use Yaml.Dom` somewhere.

Comment: @flyx Just for info: I looked into it a little bit further. It seems to be related to the `limited with` construct in `Yaml.Dom` together with the `Implicit_Dereference` aspect. I added an answer to this question with an example that reproduces the problem. I'm not sure if the error is legitimate.

Comment: @flyx The example https://github.com/yaml/AdaYaml/blob/develop/util/src/yaml-to_dom.adb compiles just fine and works like a charm. After some time I found that is necessary to put into file 'with Yaml; use Yaml;'. I think it should be part of doc example in https://ada.yaml.io/doc/Yaml.Dom/.  I put my minimal viable example as new answer .

Comment: I have GNAT 8.4.0

Answer (score 2):

Here is the minimal example I managed to work

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line;

with Yaml; use Yaml; -- this line is missing in https://ada.yaml.io/doc/Yaml.Dom/

with Yaml.Source.Text_IO;
with Yaml.Source.File;
with Yaml.Dom.Loading;
with Yaml.Dom.Node;

pragma Unreferenced (Yaml.Dom.Node);

procedure Load_Dom is
   use type Dom.Node_Kind;

   Input : Source.Pointer :=
     (if Ada.Command_Line.Argument_Count = 0 then
         Source.Text_IO.As_Source (Ada.Text_IO.Standard_Input)
      else
         Source.File.As_Source (Ada.Command_Line.Argument (1)));
   
   Document : Yaml.Dom.Document_Reference :=
     Dom.Loading.From_Source (Input);
   
   Root : constant not null access Dom.Node.Instance
     := Document.Root.Value.Data;
   
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
     ("Root node is a " & Root.Kind'Img);
end Load_Dom;
```

Comment: This is interesting and I am pretty sure that it is a workaround for a compiler bug since I can't imagine how this is justifyable on grounds of the LRM. No definition in the package `Yaml` is used in this code and even more interesting is why you would need to `use` it.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** an answer, but (for what it's worth) an addition to the comment I made to the answer of @flyx (an answer that actually seems correct). The problem with the compilation error (in GNAT CE 2020) seems to be triggered by the `limited with Yaml.Dom.Node` construct used in the package `Yaml.Dom`, together with the `Implicit_Dereference` aspect on the type `Yaml.Dom.Accessor`. The problem can be reproduced using the example below. I currently don't know if the error is actually legitimate.

**parent.ads**

```
limited with Parent.Child;

package Parent is

  type Accessor (Data : not null access Child.Instance) is null record
     with Implicit_Dereference => Data;

end Parent;
```

**parent-child.ads**

```
package Parent.Child is
   
   type Instance (Value : Integer) is null record;

end Parent.Child;
```

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Parent;
with Parent.Child;

procedure Main is
   Ref : Parent.Accessor (new Parent.Child.Instance (0));   
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Ref.Value'Image);       --  Error
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Ref.Data.Value'Image);  --  OK
end Main;
```

**output** (compiler)

```
$ gprbuild -P default.gpr 
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
main.adb:8:29: undefined selector "Value" for overloaded prefix
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

Comment: It would be interested to know if this also happens if `Child` is not a child package of `Parent`. I'm afraid I currently have little time to look into this; feel free to post this as issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: It does happen if `Child` isn’t a child package of `Parent`. Maybe because [ARM 10.1.1(12.3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-10-1-1.html#p12.3) says that the limited view of a package contains "[f]or each type_declaration occurring immediately within the visible part that is not an incomplete_type_declaration, an incomplete view of the type with no discriminant_part" - making `Value` invisible in `Parent`, I think? Not sure where the "overloaded" comes from, though.